Webpack HTML loader doesn't work along with CSS loader
Issue
I'm creating a project with Electron Forge and webpack. I added a 'public' directory to my project, and a HTML-loader plugin to resolve the imports in the HTML files.
Some parts of my webpack configuration are as follows:
export const rules: Required<ModuleOptions>["rules"] = 
[
    // Add support for native node modules
    {
        // We're specifying native_modules in the test because the asset relocator loader generates a
        // "fake" .node file which is really a cjs file.
        test: /native_modules[/\\].+\.node$/,
        use: "node-loader",
    },
    {
        test: /[/\\]node_modules[/\\].+\.(m?js|node)$/,
        parser: { amd: false },
        use: 
        {
            loader: "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader",
            options: 
            {
                outputAssetBase: "native_modules",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack)/,
        use: {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: 
            {
                transpileOnly: true,
            },
        },
    },

    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot|mp4|webm|mp3|wav|pdf|txt)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator:
        {
            filename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]",
        }
    },

    {
        test: /\.(htm|html)$/,
        use: 
        [{
            loader: "html-loader",
        }],
    },
];

export const alias =
{
    "source": path.resolve(__dirname, "source"),
    "public": path.resolve(__dirname, "public")
}

Then I'm trying to import a CSS file directly from my HTML like this:
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css" />
</head>

But the CSS styles don't appear: Bad CSS styles
My project structure
Attempts
I checked the DevTools and the HTML looks like this:
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/29125ef8bd79b19044b6.css">
    <script defer="" src="/main_window/index.js"></script>
</head>

Then I went to '/29125ef8bd79b19044b6.css', instead of CSS code, I saw something unexpected:
import API from "!../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/style-loader@3.3.4_webpack@5.94.0/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
import domAPI from "!../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/style-loader@3.3.4_webpack@5.94.0/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";
import insertFn from "!../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/style-loader@3.3.4_webpack@5.94.0/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";
import setAttributes from "!../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/style-loader@3.3.4_webpack@5.94.0/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/setAttributesWithoutAttributes.js";
import insertStyleElement from "!../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/style-loader@3.3.4_webpack@5.94.0/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertStyleElement.js";
import styleTagTransformFn from "!../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/style-loader@3.3.4_webpack@5.94.0/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleTagTransform.js";
import content, * as namedExport from "!!../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/css-loader@6.11.0_webpack@5.94.0/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./index.css";

var options = {};

options.styleTagTransform = styleTagTransformFn;
options.setAttributes = setAttributes;
options.insert = insertFn.bind(null, "head");
options.domAPI = domAPI;
options.insertStyleElement = insertStyleElement;

var update = API(content, options);

export * from "!!../../../../node_modules/.pnpm/css-loader@6.11.0_webpack@5.94.0/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./index.css";
export default content && content.locals ? content.locals : undefined;

The fishy CSS file
I don't know if this is a bug of webpack, Electron Forge or their plugins, or something is wrong with my configuration. The full project is available here on GitHub.

You seem to have two accounts: 1 and 2. Please read: I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
